# Avoid repeating the same code in 'then' and 'catch'

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is there an option to avoid repeating `this.$router.go()` in the code below and run a piece of code whatever the result is ?

```
await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
  .then((response) => {
    this.$router.go();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.$router.go();
  });
```

Comment: why are you using `async / await` approach with `.then()` and `.catch()`?

Comment: @Ifaruki Because if he doesn't, if the request fails, the `await` will prevent further execution of the function. Inlining a `then` and `catch` will mean that the action is waited for, but if the action fails, the function continues regardless once it finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it into a named function ahead of time:

```
const handle = () => {
  this.$router.go();
};
await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
  .then(handle)
  .catch(handle);
```

You could also use `.finally`, if Axios supports it, it's [a bit new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally), but a problem with `.finally` is that the Promise will "pass through" the `.finally`, so although you'll be able to call `this.$router.go` without repetition, if the `axios` call rejects, you'll end up with a rejected Promise. so you'll need to `.catch` afterwards to avoid the `await` from throwing:

```
await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
  .finally(() => {
    this.$router.go();
  })
  .catch(() => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `finally` method of a Promise:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Answer (score 1):

> ...and run a piece of code whatever the result is ?

In Axios you can do like this as per the [official docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage)

```
axios.get('url')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
    this.$router.go();
  });
```

Update: Checked this after comment by @CertainPerformance

Axios now supports [finally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) (Check under examples)

Comment: The `.then`/`.catch`/`.then` is still a bit repetitive, since he doesn't want to do anything with the result if there's a success or error, he just wants the request to finish

Comment: Valid point, in that case the first `then` can be removed, `catch` callback can be an empty function, and `go()` should be called after catch via `then` callback

Answer (score 0):

What you actually mean is this:

```
await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
  .then((response) => {
    this.$router.go();
  },(error) => {
    this.$router.go();
  });
```

because the only difference between the code you wrote and this one is: if `this.$router.go()` throws an error, then call `this.$router.go()` again. Doesn't make much sense.

And since you don't care about the `response` either, you can as well write:

```
await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user)
  .catch(() => {})
  .then(() => {
    this.$router.go();
  });
```

or better (IMO)

```
await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user).catch(noop);

this.$router.go();
```

*assuming you have defined `function noop(){}` somewhere else for further use.*

Even if it's said that you should not mix `promise.then()` and `await`, I prefer this over

```
try {
  await axios.put(`/user/` + this.data.id, this.user);
} catch (error) {}

this.$router.go();
```